# why can't i join my 2 list class together C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 List that contains, both string and int values. I have trouble joining the two of them named vare and kunde.

And if I use vare.AddRange((IEnumerable)kunde);
It gives me this eror(Sorry if its a bit messy written)

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Kunde.Program+kunde]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Kunde.Program+kunde+Vare]'.'

```
   public class kunde
        {
            public string Navn { get; set; }
            public string Adresse { get; set; }


            public kunde(string navn, string adresse)
            {
                Navn = navn;
                Adresse = adresse;
            }

        


            abstract class Ordernum
            {

                public int ID { get; set; }

            }

            class Vare : Ordernum
            {
                private static int m_Counter = 0;

                public string Navn { get; set; }
                public int Pris { get; set; }

                public Vare()
                {
                    this.ID = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Counter);

                }
```

```
   List<Vare> vare = new List<Vare>();
                List<kunde> kunde = new List<kunde>();



                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Kunder");

                            kunde.Add(new kunde(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine()));



                            Console.WriteLine("Vare");

                            vare.Add(new Vare() { Navn = Console.ReadLine(), Pris = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) });

                            vare.AddRange((IEnumerable<Vare>)kunde);

                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Clear();
```

Comment: Hi, can you [edit] your question and limit the code to the actual problem? It helps us to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Why do you expect that you _can_ do that?

Comment: Step back for a second and suppose you could do this. You have `List<Apple>` and `List<Tiger>` Your resulting list is `List<Apple>` and contains Apple elements and Tiger elements. What's going to happen when you try to access `item.Walk();` when `item` is an `Apple`?

Comment: You can only add one type of class to a List. Or at the very least they have to inherit from the same baseclass and the list should be a list of the baseclass type.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi ... or even better: interface.

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you nest classes? Don't do that unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Fildor, his main() function is located in one of the nested classes too, amazing this works at all.

Comment: Also it is unclear why you would want a subclass inside another class. Yes it can be done, but in all my years (15ish) in C#, i've rarely seen it done. It is better to make the class types not internal for a majority of applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, a `List` can only be of one type. You are trying to have a list with two different types (classes) in this case `kunde` and `Vare`.

If you want to be able to add them both to a list they need to share a common interface, and have a list of type your interface.

Comment: Note, one could have a list of `Object`s to hold differing items. But I would have to question why one would want to cross pollinate two object types into one list. Or use a Composite Collection used in WPF; but again, why would one want to do that?.

Comment: I am not sure either, but I have gotten assigned to do this by my teacher. So i was wondering what to do. Sorry for the trouble! But thanks for the help and respond.

Comment: So your teacher doesn't like you? @oli ;D No, seriously: Either he wanted you to learn that it is a bad idea or he ... well ... lacks some skills himself (which I doubt).